# list of dictionaries order by value C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I order by **value** in descending order following the dictionary list

```
        List<Dictionary<int, int>> myList = new List<Dictionary<int, int>>();
        Dictionary<int, int> obj = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        obj.Add(1, 2);
        myList.Add(obj);
        myList.Add(obj);

        Dictionary<int, int> obj2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        obj2.Add(2, 4);
        myList.Add(obj2);

        Dictionary<int, int> obj3 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        obj3.Add(3, 3);
        myList.Add(obj3);
        myList.Add(obj3);
        myList.Add(obj3);
```

expected output will be

```
[0][2,4], 
[1][3,3], 
[2][3,3], 
[3][3,3],  
[4][1,2],
[5][1,2]
```

Comment: which value do you want to order?

Comment: by second int value

Comment: What would you expect the output to be? What about if you did `obj3.Add(0,0)`?

Comment: expected output will be `[0][2,4], [1][3,3], [2][3,3], [3][3,3],  [4][1,2], [5][1,2]` for now 0 values I'm not considering :)

Comment: Use following : var results = myList.SelectMany((x, i) => x.Select(y => new { x = x, key = y.Key, value = y.Value })).OrderByDescending(x => x.value).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
  var orderedValues = myList
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
            .ToList();
```

and output the data

```
for (int i = 0; i < orderedValues.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{i}][{orderedValues[i].Key},{orderedValues[i].Value}]");
}
```